# Alignment in a table

Tags: tables

I have table with two rows and data like in the example. I would like to have a vertical alignment of before the letters alpha, beta and gamma.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]

\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    blablablalbalbla                                    &   blablablalbalbla                                                \\
    blablablalbalbla                                    &   blablablalbalbla                                                \\  

    blablablalbalbla $/\pico\meter$ bzw. $/\degree$     &   a = xxxx.xx(x)\qquad    $\alpha$ = 90                                       \\
                                                        &   b = xxx.xx(x)\qquad     $\beta$ = 96.283(3)                                 \\
                                                        &   c = xx11xx.xx(x)\qquad  $\gamma$ = 90                                   \\
        blablablalbalbla                                &   2.0741(1)                                                   \\
    blablablalbalbla                                    &                                                       \\
    blablablalbalblaaaaff                               &   blablablalbalblablablablalbalblablablablalbalbla                                \\
    blablablalbalbla                                    &   blablablalbalbla                                                    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can I do it via a second table?
Using multirows on all the other lines does not work, since I have one long blablablalbalblablablablalbalblablablablalbalbla value in there.
How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you employ a two-column top-aligned `tabular` environment to typeset the material in question.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for '\toprule' and '\bottomrule' directives
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for '\si' directive

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]

\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
    blablablalbalbla           & blablablalbalbla \\
    blablablalbalbla           & blablablalbalbla \\
    blablablalbalbla \si{\pico\meter} bzw.\ \si{\degree} 
    %% here comes the new 'tabular' env.
       & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}ll@{}}
             a = xxxx.xx(x) & $\alpha = 90$\\
             b = xxx.xx(x)  & $\beta  = 96.283(3)$ \\
             c = xxxx.xx(x) & $\gamma = 90$
         \end{tabular} \\
    blablablalbalbla           & 2.0741(1) \\
    blablablalbalbla           & \\
    blablablalbalblaaaaff      &
    blablablalbalblablablablalbalblablablabla \\
    blablablalbalbla           & blablablalbalbla \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```